# Python Dataframe print column data as a continuous string

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to print the column data of a data frame as a string.

code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'I_like':['carrots','banana','watermelon']})
df = 
       I_like
0     carrots
1      banana
2  watermelon
```

Expected output:

```
col_as_string= 
["carrots" or "banana" or "watermelon"]
```

Present code:

```
col_as_string = [ "\"%s or\""%(i) for i in df['I_like']]
col_as_string = ['"carrots or"', '"banana or"', '"watermelon or"']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
print('"{}"'.format('" or "'.join(df['I_like'])))
```

Output:

```
'"carrots" or "banana" or "watermelon"'
```